# For loop values each iteration

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if these functions do exactly the same thing:

Is:

```
  for (i=0, l=this.current_columns.length; i<l; i++) {
    if ( this.current_columns[i].text === row[0] ) {
        this.current_columns.splice(i, 1);
        EV.publish('edit_layout.current_columns', {data: [this.current_columns]})
        break;
    }
  }
```

equal to:

```
  for (i=0; i<this.current_columns.length; i++) {
    if ( this.current_columns[i].text === row[0] ) {
        this.current_columns.splice(i, 1);
        EV.publish('edit_layout.current_columns', {data: [this.current_columns]})
        break;
    }
  }
```

In the end outcome?

Comment: Have you tried them? Did they do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the first loop just stores the length of `this.current_columns` to a variable and checks `i` against it.

Comment: no, when you splice elements, the first loop will go out of the array-bounds

Comment: @da_berni: And then the loop ends.

Answer (score 3):

They actually do the same thing, but it may need some explanation:

The difference in the loop itself is that the length of the array is stored in a variable in the first version.

Storing the length in a variable means that the loop will run to the original length of the array, if the array changes inside the loop, that would be a problem.

The array happens to change in the loop, but as you also have a `break;` after that, it's not a problem. The loop ends, so it doesn't matter that the length in the variable is no longer correct.

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
for (i=0, l=this.current_columns.length; i<l; i++) {
```

the first part: `i=0, l=this.current_columns.length` is executed once, whereas `i<l` is executed at each iteration.

It is thus generally better to precalculate the boundary of a loop.
Be careful though, because sometimes your loop modifies the length of the array it traverses, you have then a choice: whether you calculate at each iteration the length of the array or you modify `i` and `l` in consequence (if you remove an element `l = l - 1`, and `i = i - 1`)